# Why is 进入 in 我们无法提供相关的API进入词库数据库?

Tags: meaning-in-context

非常抱歉 ， 我们无法提供相关的API进入词库数据库 ，这些是受到版权保护的 。

So basically they can't provide access to the database via API, but I'm wondering why they use 进入, as I thought it was related to physical entrance of a person into a place.

I have seen that usually the verb is 访问数据库, but I've never studied Chinese vocabulary related to the IT field.

Comment: I think it's `进入` = log in : `访问` = access but I'm no IT expert

Comment: I'm no expert either, but I would immediately understand 进入 as _access_ (in the sense of being allowed to get to the database at all) and 访问 as _entry_ or even _query_ (in the sense of accessing the database in a specific manner).

Comment: 进入 = enter; a generalized term that you cannot resist.  ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

进入 has two meanings:

- to go in from the outside, e.g. `进入大學` "enter the university".
- to reach a certain time period or status, e.g. `进入夏天` "become summer".

The intended meaning here is the first, **which does not have to be physical at all**. For instance, one might say "Open the options" in Chinese as `进入選項`; literally, "go into the options (menu)".

So this sentence just means "to go inside the database", i.e. accessing it.

Note that both `访问` and `进入` are in fairly common use for describing accessing a database, but with some differences. The former is more technical in nature. The phrase originally meant "to visit", and it got adopted to refer to accessing databases. For instance, you might speak of `写一个访问 Oracle 数据库的程序`, "write a program to access Oracle databases".

In contrast, using `进入` is more about connecting to, and thus being able to access the contents of, a database. A university library might say `點此進入圖書館資料庫` "click here to enter the library catalogue database", for example.

So generally, you'd use `访问` for the technical database access process, while `进入` can be used for accessing in a nontechnical sense.

Comment: I don't agree. 进入数据库 is too colloquial, it should not appear in formal text. `访问` for accessing is much better here.

Comment: @Stan I disagree. 進入 is not any more colloquial or informal than 訪問. Upon reflection however, I think 访问 and 进入 have slightly different connotations. In this vein, I believe 訪問 is more technical, referring to the connection to a database, while 進入 is more general.

Comment: Would the English equivalent be: 访问 for to "query" a database and 进入 for to "access" a database ?

Comment: `點此進入圖書館電子資料庫檢索` though a little pedantic, I would say formally speaking, it is short for "點此進入圖書館電子資料庫檢索 **頁面**", i.e. click here to enter **the webpage** for querying the library catalog database. What you really enter is the webpage, not database.

Comment: @Tara Not exactly. English "access database" encompasses aspects of both. I think an example might be to use 进入 for "logging into the library database to search for a book"; and 访问 to talk about "accessing the database using Java Data Base Connectivity". They are both fine in formal texts, but mean different concepts.

Comment: @Stan I was actually thinking "enter the database to search" when I wrote that. It doesn't have to be a webpage: 進入資料庫 is used in offline contexts as well; it is just a general sense of getting into a database so that you can use it.

Comment: @Semaphore So in the sentence I asked the question about, since it is referencing accessing the database via API, the verb should have been 访问？

Comment: @Semaphore yes it doesn't have to be a webpage, what I meant was some interface (the webpage is one of them).

Comment: @Tara The context, as I read it, is talking about not letting you into (and thus access the contents of) the database due to copyright. If so, then 进入 seems quite natural and fine to me.

Answer (score 4):

first at all, the 进入 and 访问 are two concepts in IT field.

1. the (进入 == enter or entry) meaning : you can login into a command-line of db.
2. the (访问 == access) meaning: you can access some data via APIs and you can't control the db.

BTW, I am a developer and i am so glad to help you at next time if you want.

FYI, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So in the above sentence, since I'm asking can I access the data via API, should the verb have been 访问？

Answer (score 1):

To me, it feels like that sentence is Google translated from English, however i don't feel 进入词库数据库 weird, I always say 进入 database, 进入 host.. I feel that 进入 is like more causal use and 访问 is more official and professional.

Comment: The sentence is part of an email correspondence I had with 爱词霸, so it's funny that you find it has a Google translate vibe! Maybe the correspondent changed their vocab to accommodate the foreigner.

Answer (score 1):

If the original english term is "access", "存取" is a more IT-like translation.